# How do I add an external value to a Leaflet geocode query?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

This code geocodes data from a javascript object and it is working fine:

```
var queryAddr = [{"location":"London, UK", "size":10},{"location":"Chelmsford, UK","size":160}];

geocoder = new L.Control.Geocoder.Nominatim();
for (i = 0; i < queryAddr.length; i++) {
  var yourQuery = queryAddr[i]["location"];   
  geocoder.geocode(yourQuery, function(results) {    
    x_coor = results[0].center.lng;
    y_coor = results[0].center.lat;
    L.circleMarker([y_coor, x_coor]).addTo(map);
  });
}
```

But what if I want to add the size value using the radius option for circleMarker? I tried doing this but it says the value is undefined.

```
geocoder = new L.Control.Geocoder.Nominatim();
for (i = 0; i < queryAddr.length; i++) {
  var yourQuery = queryAddr[i]["location"];   
  geocoder.geocode(yourQuery, function(results) {    
    x_coor = results[0].center.lng;
    y_coor = results[0].center.lat;
    circleSize = queryAddr[i]["size"]; 
    L.circleMarker([y_coor, x_coor], {radius: circleSize}).addTo(map);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access the outside scope from inside the callback function.
so queryAddr is not visible for this line:

```js
circleSize = queryAddr[i]["size"];
```

so move it outside the geocoder call and use map to iterate over address items

like this :

```js
geocoder = new L.Control.Geocoder.Nominatim();

queryAddr.map(function(itemAddr) {
  geocoder.geocode(itemAddr["location"], function(results) {    
    x_coor = results[0].center.lng;
    y_coor = results[0].center.lat;
    L.circleMarker([y_coor, x_coor], {radius: itemAddr["size]}).addTo(map);
  });
});
```

Comment: When I do this, 160 returns twice so the 2 circles end up becoming the same size. Seems to be only getting the last value.

Comment: right, it's async calls that would finish after the loop ends. I rewrote it with a proper map handling instead of FOR loop which is better suited for this type of actions